# How to use the value from an RxJS observable subscribe call

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a `subject` that passes in an object from another component. in the subscribe, I assign what has been passed into a class property.

[image]

I then want to use this property to help me reload an `ag-Grid` which helps with the styling. However, if I call it after the value has been assigned in the asynchronous subscribe call, it uses the previous value of `this.ViewContext`.

I have even purposely set it in the complete call but this doesn't work neither.

However, if I call it on a button click afterwards the subscribe call, it works... (or gets the last value passed into by the subject)

[image]

[image]

Is there any way I can do this without a further event (like the button click?)

-------------- The Answer ------------

Based on the answer below, this is the change in code

[image]
[image]

This now takes the new value.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, your problem is related to change detection.
You should inject 'private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef' in your component.
then call cdr.detectChanges() when your value is updated.

Comment: Yes bingo, thank you, I will read up on this, thanks